# Ubuntu 13.04 rhythmbox doesn't recognise title and artist

Tags: 13.04, rhythmbox

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04.  Rhythm box recognized my audio CD Artists and Titles in 12.10 but 13.04 just shows unknown for both

Comment: I cannot play anything with Rhythmbox, I just use VLC for now!!!

Comment: are they of a certain file type? did you install the restricted-extras?

Comment: I did add restricted extra's and Yes they are just average country and jazz commercial audio CD's.  Ubuntu 12.10 and Rhythmbox 2.97 show artist and title fine. Ubuntu 13.04 and Rhythmbox 2.98 show all my audio CD's as unkown artist unkown title.

Comment: I have a similar issue in 13.04 and Rhythmbox 2.98. I did a fresh install of 13.04 and transferred all my music from an external HDD, and in Rhythmbox shows Unknown for the Year for every single artist/album. Needless to say for me this is super frustrating. I installed Banshee to compare and it was able to show Year for every artist/album. Must be some issue with Rhythmbox.

Comment: @dswhite85 - have you filed a bug report on the rhythmbox section of the bugzilla website?

Answer (score 0):

try to purge rhythmbox and then reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox

sudo apt-get install rhythmbox gnome
```

(as purging rhythmbox removes gnome too)

Comment: Would it be wise to use apt-get clean and autoremove?